# MATLAB cannot read function in the same folder with correct name

Tags: matlab

I have several functions in one folder. When I try to call functions in my main script, none of them are able to be performed.

I double-checked the name of my functions and added the path to the directory. I cannot think about other problems. If I put the functions at the end of the main script, it does run. But I want to keep the file neat.

I also double-checked the licenses are valid.

Comment: What do you get when you type "which your_function_name"? Is your main script in a different folder than your functions? When you type "path" do you see the directory where your functions are? If you change directory to the directory where the functions are, do they then run?

Comment: 1. 'which' returns the same folder path.

Comment: 2. when i change path, by which i call the function in the command window directly, it does not work. it says: "xxx is not found in the current folder or on the MATLAB path, but exists in: xxx". then i added that path and try run the script. it says the same thing again

Comment: I think screenshots could be helpful here. Do you have the "Current folder" open in the user interface. Are the functions shown in the list there? What happens if you double-click one of them? Are they listed if you type `dir`? _Are the functions called the same as the .m-files?_

Comment: i'm not sure how to add a screenshot. but to all your questions, my answer is YES. that's why i am so confused. I'm not a newbie to MATLAB. all these happened after my old license expired and i re-installed the app.